# Regarding union and multiple integer values

Tags: c, unions

I'm getting into C and I experimented with union. My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union date {
 int year  ;
 char month;
 char day  ;
 };

int main() {
 union date birth;
 birth.year = 1984;
 birth.month = 7;
 birth.day = 28;
 printf("%d, %d, %d\n",birth.year, birth.month, birth.day);
 // return 1820,28,28
 return 0;
}
```

- 1984 is written in binary as 0111 1100 0000
- 7 is written in binary as 0110
- 28 is written in binary as 0001 1100

I understand that because of union, `birth.year` has the value of 0111 0001 1100 which is 1820. But I do not understand why does `birth.month` return as value 28.

Comment: I guess you can access only the value which was last modified, is not it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: That's a thorny issue. I interpret the C standard as guaranteeing that you *can* use unions for type-punning (like `memcpy()`).

Comment: @L.M what did you expect `month` to contain? (no pun intended, but you should mention what you expected to see)

Comment: @EOF Certainly you can, for sure, just need to be double-careful, you may end up being in trap. :) What I missed to say earlier is "safely".

Comment: @SouravGhosh Assuming you're on an implementation where `char` is equivalent to `unsigned char`, you can safely access `.month` and `.day` without worrying about trap representations.

Comment: @EOF Right, but that should be same of the other compatible types also, right? Like `long`, `signed long` and `long int`....or am I missing something?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: AFAIK, only `unsigned char` (and the fixed-width integer types) is guaranteed to be able to represent [two to the power of (bitsize)] - 1 different values (which leaves nothing for padding-bits or trap representations).

Comment: @EOF Hmm..makes sense, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.2.1, (*emphasis mine*)

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. **The value of at
>   most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time.** A pointer to a
>   union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bitfield,
>   then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

So, the basis of your expectation is wrong. You cannot have values for *all* the members of an union at the same time, you can have only one.

Also, from chapter §6.5.2.3, Footnote 95,

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is **not the same as the member last used to
>   store a value** in the object, the **appropriate part of the object representation of the value is re-interpreted
>   as an object representation in the new type** as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
>   punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

Here, the last assigned value, `day` happens to be of the same size of that of `month`, so when you try to read `day`, it returns the value of that of the `month`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats what i didnt understood.

Comment: @L.M You're welcome. :) You can also consider [accepting an answer that helped you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062), which is the StackOverflow way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've misunderstood the purpose of a union. If you want an object that stores a set of properties (e.g. `d.year`, `d.month`, `d.day`), you need a struct.

Unions, in short, let you put one of a number of different types within a single variable. Say for example that you're implementing a filesystem. Let's say you want a variable `current_block` that can refer to either a super block or a data block, defined by `struct super_block` and `struct data_block` respectively. Then you could do:

```
union block_generic{
    struct super_block;
    struct data_block;
}

union block_generic current_block;
```

Now `current_block` can be either a super_block or a data_block.

EDIT: Just wanted to add a quick addendum about the actual usage of unions. Continuing the above example, to treat `current_block` as a super block, e.g., in order to access the filesystem's number of inodes, you would do `current_block.super_block.n_inodes` (what I mean to point out is that you don't give direct treatment to the union variable, you specify which "type hat," so to speak, it should wear.

Answer (score 1):

A union stores all its members in the same space and the data present in that space corresponds to whichever member was written last. A union is exactly as large as its largest member. You don't mention your specific platform, but assuming a fairly recent GCC on a modern x86 Windows, MacOS, or desktop Linux, `char` is probably 8 bits and `int` is probably 32 bits, making your date union look something like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
\_______________ year ________________/
\ month /
\_ day _/
```

Let's walk through your use of `union date birth`, shall we? Starting with `birth.year = 1984;`, we have (keep in mind that x86 is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness))

```
1100 0000 0000 0111 0000 0000 0000 0000
\_______________ year ________________/
\ month /
\_ day _/
```

Then `birth.month = 7;`:

```
0000 0111 0000 0111 0000 0000 0000 0000
\_______________ year ________________/
\ month /
\_ day _/
```

And finally, `birth.day = 28;`:

```
0001 1100 0000 0111 0000 0000 0000 0000
\_______________ year ________________/
\ month /
\_ day _/
```

It should be clear that writing to any member of a union will overwrite at least part of all other members.

Contrast that with a struct, which has unique storage space for all its members, making it at least as large as all its members added together (it may be larger do to padding). If you replace all instances of `union` in your sample code with `struct`, you'd get something that looks like this in memory at the end:

```
1100 0000 0000 0111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 0001 1100
\_______________ year ________________/ \ month / \_ day _/
```

The data for each member is fully intact and can be correctly retrieved with `birth.year`, `birth.month`, or `birth.day`.

Answer (score 0):

A union is a special data type available in C that allows to store different data types in the same memory location.

That said, you must use one variable at a time.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm

Answer (score 0):

This entirely misunderstands what a union is. A union is an array of values that all start from at the same memory location; what you need to use if you want to store several separate values in one data type is a struct.

For example, with a union you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union _myunion
{
    int32_t s;
    uint32_t u;
} myunion;

int main()
{
    myunion u;
    u.s = -1;
    printf("%d %u\n", u.s, u.u);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-1 4294967295
```

Basically, you assign one value and all union members get that value; if it's represented differently in a different type, so be it.

Within a struct, each variable occupies its own memory location, so if you wanted to store a complete date including the year, month, and day as separate variables within the struct, you could do so without any issues.